# Size dimensions iOS don't make sense

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, screen

I'm trying to look up the bounds of my screen in Portrait mode (set to only Portrait in Xcode) using Swift but everything I try does not place my sprite on a sensible position.

```
let screenWidth = self.size.width;
let screenHeight = self.size.height;

var posX: CGFloat = screenWidth;
var posY: CGFloat = screenHeight / 2;
```

Sprite is positioned out of screen in portrait. Turning the screen reveals the sprite far right of the screen (width), in the middle (height).

So you'd think I should just turn around these values.

```
let screenWidth = self.size.height;
let screenHeight = self.size.width;
```

Nope. Still out of screen in portrait. Turning the screen again reveals it, but halfway between middle and border of the right screen border (width), and not in the middle (height).

So I guess I could try to get the values in some other way.

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width;
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height;
```

It's visible in portrait!... But on the far left (not on the border) and not in the middle of the screen's height either. Turning the screen places it a bit left of the middle, and still not center of height.

I think you can guess what I tried next.

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height;
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width;
```

Pretty far on the bottom, slighty right of the middle in portrait. Turning screen makes no sense either.

I'm kinda lost. Googled and tried things for hours but no result.

Comment: Wouldn't it help if you told us what the strange values are?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: If you are using SpriteKit then you should not be setting positions based on your device's screen size, but on the SKScene dimensions.

Comment: Isn't self.size doing this? It's called in didMoveToView function of my GameScene class.